# Inner product for $M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{C})$ is...?

Tags: matrices, inner-products

I can't seem to find a reference which confirms this for me.

I know that the standard inner product for $A,B \in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ is given by $\langle A,B\rangle = \operatorname{Tr}(B^{T}A)$.

Would the standard inner product for $A,B \in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{C})$ be given by $\langle A,B\rangle = \operatorname{Tr}(B^{\dagger}A)$?

This is the only thing that makes sense, but I can't find anything about the matter online. I think this would give a valid "hermitian inner product" in the sense that we have $\langle A,B\rangle = \overline{\langle B,A\rangle}$.

Comment: Yes, this is the [Frobenius inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product).

Comment: You are right. A bit of googling brought up this http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis515/cis515-15-sl9.pdf  -- see example 5

Comment: Thank you very much! I couldn't remember the name, that definitely rings a bell!